# Principle of substitution -- fields

Tags: linear-algebra, field-theory, definition

Could someone possibly explain this definition (applied to ***fields***) to me?

> The principle of substitution: In a field F, we can, in any formula involving an element $\alpha\in F$, replace $\alpha$ by any other element $\alpha'\in F$ such that $\alpha'=\alpha$.

What is the difference between $\alpha'$ and $\alpha$? What is the motivation behind this principle?

Thanks.

Comment: It might make more sense to think of this as a definition of equality.  $\alpha = \alpha'$ if and only if $f(\alpha) = f(\alpha')$ for any formula $f$ (whatever you mean by "formula").

Comment: What is the source of the quoted statement?

Comment: *Linear Algebra -- An Introductory Approach* by Charles Curtis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see how this differs from any other use of what has also gotten called "the rule of replacement".  The difference between α′ and α could be a number of things.  Generally speaking though, they will differ in their form, or how a formula gets evaluated to an element.  Applying this principle, can make an expression shorter, longer, harder to evaluate, or easier to evaluate.  For instance, in a field, say we have (a+((b*c)+(b*d))).  Well, since distribution holds ((x*y)+(x*z))=(x*(y+z)), by the principle here (a+((b*c)+(b*d))) becomes (a+(b*(c+d))), which I think you would agree as a much easier expression to evaluate and work with in general.

If you look at certain logic texts, you'll find this principle outside the context of a field called "the rule of replacement", where "substitution" means something slightly different.